More efficient way to use Symmetrical Difference tool for layer with many features
I have a layer called habmap_combined with 24,934 features and a high number of vertices (it was a raster and is now a shapefile).
I have another shapefile called waterbodies, for which I want to replace the features in habmap_combined that it overlaps, so those areas will now have vegForm 'waterbody' instead of whatever the habmap_combined says it is (usually 'undefined'). The end result will be a new shapefile with the features of both habmap_combined and waterbodies.
I have tried to use the 'Symmetrical differences' tool in QGIS but it simply gets stuck loading – it doesn't seem like it can handle this. I have also tried in R using this code:
# Validate geometries to fix any invalid polygons
habmap <- st_make_valid(habmap)
waterbodies <- st_make_valid(waterbodies)

# Calculate the symmetric difference
diff <- st_difference(habmap, waterbodies)

But likewise it took far too long to run and eventually had an error (apologies but I don't know what the error was – I didn't write it down and it has since gone from the console).
Is there an alternative option to achieve what I want to? Or is it simply a question of having a computer with higher processing power? I have tried on both mac and windows.

Simplifying the geometries (reducing the number of vertices) might help. And you should make sure your data has a spatial index.

To add to other suggestions, both input layers should be in the same coordinate system.  If the shapefile from the raster has large areas of pixel polygons with the same attributes and you don't need the pixels, dissolve on those attributes before running the overlay.  If there are scattered pixel polygons that you eventually will want to get rid of you might do that before the overlay.  Some sort of aggregation or filtering can be used although that might be easier on the raster if you have it.  You might snap your hab_map to the waterbody prior to the overlay as well.

A typical way to solve this is to reduce the size and complexity of the input geometries by first doing an intersection of them with a grid-layer. This can give an enormous difference in processing time.
After processing you can then apply a dissolve to recombine the results if needed.

Having large complex geometries will slow down processing.
Try:

Multipart To Singleparts

Subdivide


3. And  Create Spatial Index
On both input layers

you're going about it backwards. Most times when you convert a raster to a shapefile you meaninglessly large number of vertices (at least until you do simplification on the boundaries) and often an equally meaningless large number of features, as small as a single pixel.
Instead of converting the raster to polygons, take the shapefile and convert it to a raster mask. Then use the raster calculator to replace the veg_form attribute with waterbody. If you really have to have a shapefile when done, take this combined raster and run the polygonize algorithm on it.

In addition to the other excellent ideas presented,I would recommend that you run the Fix Geometries tool on both of the input layers. This tool repairs and/or removes any geometry errors which would cause Symmetrical Differences to subsequently fail.
